# reload UITableView from NSOperation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsinvocationoperation

I have written following code to reload a UITableView from a NSInvocationOperation. However the interface does not update for a long time after calling `[tableview reloadData]`.

Apple documentation says that delegate method won't be called within NSOperation.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self
                                            selector:@selector(connectToServer)
                                            object:nil];

[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
[queue autorelease];

- (void) connectToServer
{
    ...
    ...
    [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that UI updates must occur on the main thread, and reloadData is being called from a background thread via the NSOperationQueue.

You can use the NSObject method [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) to ensure such updates occur on the main thread.

```
- (void) connectToServer
{
    ...
    ...
    [tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
            withObject:nil
            waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Additionally, the `NSOperationQueue` should not be a local variable. It should be a retained property of this class, and only released in `dealloc`.

Comment: i tried it already, it gives output after some time in ios5 as same..can you pls help?